# DC-DC buck converter's MOSFET or IGBT?

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, buck, electric-vehicle

Motor Specifications:

- Rated power: 50 kW
- Rated voltage: 200V DC
- Rated current: 250A

Battery Specifications:

- Nominal voltage: 400V DC
- Capacity: 50 kWh

Design Requirements of the DC-DC Converter

- Input Voltage Range: Specify the range (300V - 450V DC).
- Output Voltage and Current: Detail the required output voltage (200V
  DC) and current (250A).
- Efficiency and Ripple Voltage: State the efficiency (>95%) and ripple
  voltage (<2% of output voltage) requirements.

For these voltage value and efficiency; should I use IGBT or MOSFET?
Because I have read that IGBT is excellent for > 100 V (high voltages) but it is not that much in efficiency. I have done the calculations needed and  it is attached below:

[image: Analytical Calculations]

So, thanks for help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This sounds like a design exercise. Can you show what work you have done so far, and what points you are stuck on? What range of IGBTs/MOSFETs are you selecting from? Are there any other design constraints, such as cooling capacity, cost, size, etc.?

Comment: IGBTs generally can't be used for > 25 kHz. So you'll end up with a very large inductor which also means a quite possibly noisy converter.

Comment: IGBTs are becoming less and less useful now that you can get SiC MOSFETs to fill the role they used to be used in.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have done the analytical calculation, but I am stuck in the efficiency calculation, because as I have read I should select the components then I should see the power loss of every component.

Comment: @Hearth Thank you Sir, Are SiC MOSFETs good for this high voltage design? And how I know the power losses for every component? Because I need to calculate the efficiency of the this buck converter. Is it from the datasheet? Because I am not an experienced student. Sorry for overwriting..

Comment: @BadrAl-Sabri Please do not call me sir. SiC MOSFETs are suitable for high-power DC-DC converters, yes. But calculating efficiency can't be done until much later in the design, when you know things like exactly what inductors and capacitors will be used (down to the exact part number).

Comment: Why use a buck converter on a motor, the inductor is going to be huge it won't allow the to go in reverse. The motor is already a big inductor, with a H-bridge you get speed control and reverse...

Comment: @bobflux I used buck converter to lower down the input voltage from 400 V to 200 V.

Comment: @Hearth Thanks. I will choose the other components and choose the MOSFET at last.

Comment: Definitely a job for SiC FETs, though you might get by with GaN FETs too, but you'd have to be careful about the maximum voltage (with ringing, etc).  IGBTs would work, but as others have said would lead to a larger solutions size and lower efficiency.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I designed and put a 5 kW full bridge converter into mass production using IGBTs switching at 65 kHz back in 2010. So you certainly can operate them above 25 kHz. Since then, MOSFETs have eaten into their market share from the bottom.

Comment: @winny `So you certainly can operate them above 25 kHz.` this doesn't apply to all IGBTs and all applications. It comes down to IGBT itself, cooling, efficiency and loss management. "Generally", especially for HV and high-current applications, 25 kHz usually becomes high. If you have time, please check some 600+ Volts and 200+ Amps IGBT modules' specs. The maximum recommended frequency is usually clearly specified, and for most of them it's not higher than 30 or 40 kHz.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I agree with you, most applications run slower. If I would get the same job today, I would have used SiC MOSFETs instead.

Answer (score 2):

**Quick answer:**
SiC MOSFETs would be better than IGBTs for efficiency, but may result in higher cost, depending on whether the benefits of SiC (specifically higher switching frequency for a given power loss) translate to lower overall costs for the passive components.

Second comment: I recommend investigating the multi-phase buck converter to see the benefits it provides over a single buck converter.

**Longer Answer:**
I note that the paper image in the question suggests this is for an Electric Vehicle (not mentioned in the text part of the question).  Assuming that this design is for an EV, then one important aspect is range, and to get the highest range it very important to consider all sources of power loss that occur **at low motor operating power**.  This is because, at a steady speed, the power used by the car is quite low, certainly much lower than the maximum power rating of the motor; typically it is in the range of 10 to 15% of the maximum power rating, depending on the intended purpose of the vehicle, and whether its acceleration must be high (above average), average, or lower than average.

To maximise battery range, the efficiency at output power in the range of 10 to 20% of motor rating is very important.  In this case, a topology worth considering is an **interleaved multi-phase buck converter** comprised of several identical switching arms and their associated filter components (DC bus capacitors and output inductors).

Image below: three-phase buck converter.  Note that the input and output capacitors may also be spread out to one per phase.
[image]

One benefit of a multi-phase buck is that it allows the motor drive management system to shut-down some phases to access improved efficiency in the low load range.
Image below shows this high efficiency at light load (for a 5-phase buck converter).

[image]

Another benefit is the reduction in ripple current flowing in filter capacitors, which reduces power loss in those capacitors, refer image below:
[image]

All images from:
Texas Instruments, publication SLVA882B – APRIL 2017 – REVISED APRIL 2021.
Application Report
Multiphase Buck Design From Start to Finish (Part 1).
Author: Carmen Parisi.

https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva882b/slva882b.pdf